# Paw shaped keyhole in hospital

Tags: lone-survivor

In the hospital I noticed a paw-shaped keyhole; You only seems to take notice of it after "new game plus" e.g. beating the game. Is there some way to open the door? Since it's optional and apparently NG+ only I assume it's required for a certain ending?

Comment: where is the keyhole exactly? can you take a screenshot of it?

Comment: @DavidToh it's in the hospital just passed the checkin sheet (spoilers) which will allow you to enter the last room of the game. I'll get a screenshot tonight.

Answer (score 1):

You have to finish the cat adoption side quest, then feed your cat all five tins, and finally offer it the cat plush. You'll get the ability to create

> Chilled Can of Soda or Chilled Mexican Cola

[Source](http://lonesurvivor.wikia.com/wiki/Optional_Quests#Cat_Key)